Unsure about interpretation of Lock-in amplifier frequency sweep data
I am using a Lock-in amplifier but have very little experience in electronics. I am measuring the vibrations of a mechanical system (think springs and masses), and using the lock-in together with an acceleration sensor. To do the measurement i use the frequency sweeper setting of my lock-in (Zurich instruments MLFI), from which i get a spectrum with Volt on the y axis and frequency on the x axis. From this measurement i want to calculate and plot other spectra, such as the PSD/ASD, and to calculate the absolute displacement. My main question is whether what i am doing actually is correct. An example of a typical spectrum that i take is:

I am taking the output of the R-channel, and plotting it as above. To get the power spectrum, I square the measured amplitude.
$$PS = {V_{LIA}^2}$$
To get the power spectral density i divide by the equivalent noise bandwidth:
$$PSD = \frac{PS}{ENBW}$$
$$ ENWB = \frac{1}{2 \pi}*\int_0^\infty |{\frac{H(j\omega)}{H_{max}}}|^2 d \omega$$
Then from the PSD i can get the ASD by taking the square root again. to Convert everything from Volts to meters, i can use the calibration i have and the fact that $$a = \ddot{x} = A \omega^2 sin(\omega t)  $$ such that the measured signal on the lock-in is $$V_{LIA} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}S A \omega^2 $$
where the sensor has a sensitivity S, and the factor 1/sqrt(2) comes from the fact that the lock-in displaces the rms value. Is this a valid way to convert the measurement data of my experiment into a power/amplitude density spectrum? I have a feeling that i am missing some things, but i am having difficulty finding what that is.

OK you have an amplitude vs frequency plot. But is it a spectrum, or just an amplitude versus frequency plot? Since you're using a lock in amplifier, it's probably the latter. In a spectrum, each bin shows the amount of energy within the frequency space covered by the bin. But perhaps all the plot says is "we sent a signal of X Hertz on the output, and got a signal of Y volts on the input". So which one is it?

I mean a spectrum represents one signal, so the concept of spectral power density applies. But in the other case, the plot simply represents the results of many different tests with many different signals, so the concept of spectral power density makes no sense. In this case, if the stimulus signal is constant, the plot represents frequency response, not spectrum.

@bobflux I suppose it is a frequency response then: the Lock-in sends a signal at a frequency, which shakes a vibration table at that frequency. The acceleration sensor then captures the response of the mechanical resonator, in volt. Is it then true that, apart from finding the resonant frequency/Q-factor, and saying "at this frequency with this input amplitude X, the system shakes at an output amplitude Y", there is not much more information to be got from such a measurement?

Yes in this case the plot gives you volts directly, no need to do any conversion with spectral density. If you know the sensor response you can convert to physical displacement.
